# Strange IP routing - ping not working

Tags: ip, route, bitbucket

From my server I can't clone repos from bitbucket.org nor reaching bitbucket.org using ping. Everything worked up to now with the current configuration.

Here is what I found out up to now:

Trying to ping using https://ping.eu/ping to bitbucket.org works.

```
$ ping bitbucket.org 
PING bitbucket.org (18.205.93.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
=> timeout

$ ping google.com
=> works

$ ping apple.com
=> timeout

$ traceroute bitbucket.org
traceroute to bitbucket.org (18.205.93.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.29.103.28 (172.29.103.28)  0.035 ms  0.020 ms  0.018 ms
 2  vl-1960.gw-distp-a.kw.nbz.fr.oneandone.net (195.20.243.93)  0.315 ms *  0.312 ms
 3  ae-7.bb-b.bs.kae.de.oneandone.net (195.20.243.7)  0.837 ms  0.856 ms  0.877 ms
 4  ae-5.bb-c.act.fra.de.oneandone.net (212.227.120.19)  2.800 ms  2.812 ms  2.789 ms
 5  ae-2-0.bb-a.fra3.fra.de.oneandone.net (212.227.120.89)  4.947 ms  5.021 ms  5.041 ms
 6  xe-3-1-0-275.fra20.ip4.tinet.net (213.200.65.205)  2.981 ms  3.263 ms  3.234 ms
 7  et-10-3-0.cr4-nyc2.ip4.gtt.net (213.254.214.10)  86.464 ms  86.464 ms  86.400 ms
 8  a100-gw.ip4.gtt.net (173.205.58.70)  86.420 ms  86.446 ms  86.461 ms
 9  52.93.1.85 (52.93.1.85)  88.891 ms 52.93.1.91 (52.93.1.91)  93.428 ms 52.93.1.95 (52.93.1.95)  87.744 ms
10  52.93.1.20 (52.93.1.20)  86.733 ms 52.93.1.52 (52.93.1.52)  86.760 ms 52.93.1.24 (52.93.1.24)  86.703 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  54.239.110.217 (54.239.110.217)  106.686 ms 54.239.110.247 (54.239.110.247)  109.190 ms 54.239.110.205 (54.239.110.205)  113.701 ms
15  54.239.109.181 (54.239.109.181)  91.045 ms 54.239.111.83 (54.239.111.83)  91.948 ms 54.239.109.113 (54.239.109.113)  92.917 ms
16  52.93.24.188 (52.93.24.188)  91.536 ms * 52.93.27.219 (52.93.27.219)  91.989 ms
17  72.21.197.227 (72.21.197.227)  91.062 ms 72.21.197.245 (72.21.197.245)  91.013 ms 72.21.197.249 (72.21.197.249)  91.034 ms
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
=> continues with asterisks
```

What does that mean? Is there a problem in a router far away? Is there a bottleneck to reach bitbucket.org?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I can‘t make a connection to bitbucket.org.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Please see the question. I cant't even ping which means the problem is on the lower layers of the netwoking stack.

Comment: That site blocks both ping and traceroute, and still works perfectly. You need to be specific as to what happens when you try to use git, or https, or anything that you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that bitbucket.org blocks ping IPV4 but not IPV6. My git uses https and indeed this totally independent of ICMP from a server administrator's point of view..

Answer (score 1):

**ping** alias **ICMP echo request** is time to time blocked by administrator. This seems to be the case. You are writing that using [ping.eu/ping](https://ping.eu/ping) it is working but you probably "forgot" to mention that the referred site is sucessfull using IPv6:

`--- PING bitbucket.org(2406:da00:ff00::22c2:513) 56 data bytes ---
64 bytes from 2406:da00:ff00::22c2:513: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 2406:da00:ff00::22c2:513: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 2406:da00:ff00::22c2:513: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 2406:da00:ff00::22c2:513: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=100 ms`

In case you force to ping the IPv4 using the same site there is also no response...

Your request starting with "**I can't clone repos from bitbucket.org**." I guess you are communicating using http / https and this service seems to be working...

*IPv6*

```
$ curl -v -i bitbucket.org
* About to connect() to bitbucket.org port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2406:da00:ff00::3403:4be7...
* Connected to bitbucket.org (2406:da00:ff00::3403:4be7) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: bitbucket.org
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Sun, 02 Dec 2018 17:26:13 GMT
< Location: https://bitbucket.org/
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host bitbucket.org left intact
```

*IPv4*

```
$ curl -4 -v -i bitbucket.org
* About to connect() to bitbucket.org port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 18.205.93.0...
* Connected to bitbucket.org (18.205.93.0) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: bitbucket.org
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Sun, 02 Dec 2018 17:26:25 GMT
< Location: https://bitbucket.org/
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 0

< 
* Connection #0 to host bitbucket.org left intact
```